# Error "The application server could not be contacted" pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, windows10, pgadmin

He instalado PostgreSQL 10.5 y pgadmin 4 versión 3.2 pero cuando trato de iniciar el pg admin 4 aparece este error:

> "The application server could not be contacted".

Comment: En casos parecidos al tuyo la solución ha sido borrar todo lo que haya en el directorio: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin`   (haz copia de seguridad de ese contenido en otra parte por si acaso).  Ten en cuenta que se trata de un directorio oculto. [Lee esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45823367/5587982)  (y las otras), para más detalles.

Answer (score -1):

Vine acá buscando la solución al mismo error que obtuve luego de una instalación limpia de Postgres, pero en mi caso, la solución propuesta por A. Cedano no funcionó.

---

Sé que mi respuesta no responde directamente tu pregunta pero DBeaver Community es una buena alternativa para PosgreSQL y otras baSes de datos, si no necesitas un DB Manager Web, y funciona tanto en Windows como en Linux.

Answer (score -1):

Borra todo lo que está dentro de la carpeta:

```
C:\Users\*TU_USUARIO*\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin
```

Busca `pgAdmin4` en el menú de inicio y luego ejecuta como administrador